beginning a sentence with as - correct usage
I've done some research regarding the use of 'as' in a sentence and cannot find what I'm looking for.
My example:
1:She set up the computer and it still wouldn't work, as despite her efforts, she had not read the instructions properly.
2:** As night turned to day**, she had failed to get any hours of sleep.
Is 1: correct usage with as? or is that a comma splice? In these instances, can you choose whether to start a new sentence with as or does the context dictate that you must use a comma or it won't make sense. I cannot see a difference between as night turned to day or as despite her efforts other than one is starting a sentence and the other is part of sentence?
https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/using-as-like#:~:text=We%20often%20use%20the%20structure,expensive%20as%20the%20other%20hotel.

As surely as night follows day, this question will generate an open-ended set of sentences starting with as.  Maybe you've seen some specific "unidiomatic" examples, but the general idea that starting an utterance with as might be somehow incorrect is just ludicrous. Why would you think such a thing?

Apparently, the sun rises as surely as night follows day AND day follows night put together. As my grandmother was wont to say: As sure as eggs is eggs, tomorrow will be a new day.

You don't have the right punctuation: She set up the computer, and it still wouldn't work, as, despite her efforts, she had not read the instructions properly. Now it works.

The comma after as is a stylistic choice, and the modern trend would be not to include it. There's nothing wrong with Hannah herself embodies this ambivalence, as despite her repeated characterization of new media as negative, she happily embraces new technology when it suits her.

First point: it's perfectly ok to begin a sentence with as:

As the comments are pointing out, "as" can be at the start of a sentence!

Second point: your confusion with your example sentences may be because as means different things in each case:

She set up the computer and it still wouldn't work, as despite her efforts, she had not read the instructions properly.

Here as means because, and it can be placed at any point in the sentence where its connecting clause makes sense:

As she had not read the instructions properly, when she set up the computer it still wouldn't work, despite her best efforts.

With the second sentence:

As night turned to day, she had failed to get any hours of sleep.

Here as is a time marker. It's not saying that her lack of sleep was caused by the sun rising. It's saying that when the sun rose, that was the point at which it was clear she had gone a night without any sleep. I would say it slightly differently (but still with as at the beginning of the sentence):

As night turned to day, she was aware that she had failed to get any sleep.

There will be many other possible wordings, but for me the key is that as (used as a time marker like this) should match two things that happen at the same time.

Just right about two uses.
